# React state not being (re)set after a change in the Firebase database and returning his initial state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I want to reset a state after a change occurred in the Firebase database. My code is looking like this:

```
 const [lists, setLists] = useState({});

 //GET THE DATA FOR THE LISTS
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      let dataObject = {};
      await listsRef.once('value', snap => {
        snap.forEach(function(result) {
          firebase
            .database()
            .ref('lists')
            .child(result.key)
            .on('value', snap => {
              dataObject[snap.val().id] = snap.val();
              setLists(dataObject);
            });
        });
      });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [props.ListUpdated]);

  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(lists).length > 0 ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      <StyledMain role="main">
        <Layout currentUser={currentUser}>
          {Object.keys(widgets).map(key => {
            return (
              <Card
                id={widgets[key].typeId}
                key={widgets[key].typeId}
                type={widgets[key].type}
                UserIndicator="right"
              >
                <CardContent scrollbar={false}>
                  {createComponent(lists)}
                </CardContent>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </Layout>
      </StyledMain>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : (
    <div>Loading</div>
  );
```

But after a change occurred in the Firebase database the lists is not being set and showing his initial state.

Why is the state not being reset with the new values from the DB?

Comment: Where do you check the updated state

Comment: I have updated the code above. I'm checking the state in the return